# How to Change Access Denied Route in .Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm having trouble with Roles and routes
I have an Account Controller and I'm using Asp Identity in one of my controllers. It requires a specific Role to access it. The problem is, I want it to redirect the **Unauthorized User** to the login page "Account/Login" but it is redirecting me to "Account/AccessDenied"

I tried the following but it didn't work

```
 services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(option =>
           {
               option.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
               
           }).AddEntityFrameworkStores <AppIdentityDbContext>();
```

And here I'm editing the paths

```
services
        .AddAuthentication()
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "account/login";
            options.LogoutPath = "account/logout";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "account/login";
            
        });
```

Here is the Controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin , secretary")]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {

            options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";  //in your case /Account/Login
            options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Account/logout";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/login";
        });

        services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie();
```

Further, if you are using .net core 1.x, and want to migrate to 2.0 or later, please follow this [Microsoft migration article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-2.1)